# yelp api v3 javascript how to get access token

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, yelp

I'm learning how to use it but not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "POST",
      url: "https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token",
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: "my_client_id",
      client_secret: "my_client_secret",
      success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        console.log(data,textStatus,jqXHR);
      }
    });
```

my_client_id and my_client_secret are got from yelp. The error in browser looks like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Edit:

Tried again with

```
  yelpTokenURL = "https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="
    + id + "&client_secret=" + secret;
  jQuery.post(yelpTokenURL, function(){
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Got error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://...
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this thread, it helped me get the access_token
https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/59

It's using the postman chrome app, it does everything for you in terms of getting the access token.

Hope this helped.

Best,
Will

Comment: You may want to consider adding the relevant code/commands in case the link becomes obsolete